# Why does this Haskell code compile?

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
uncurry :: (a-> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c    
id :: a -> a
```

Invoking `uncurry id` results in a function of type: `(b -> c, b) -> c`

How do we get this result?

How can you use id (a -> a) as the first parameter to uncurry, which requires a (a -> b -> c) function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's easier to understand if we try and look at it from the point of *making the types work out:* figuring out what we need to do to `id`'s type to get it to fit the shape required by `uncurry`. Since we have:

```
id :: a -> a
```

we also have:

```
id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
```

This can be seen by substituting `b -> c` for `a` in the original type of `id`, just as you might substitute `Int` instead when figuring out the type of `id 42`. We can then drop the parentheses on the right-hand side, since `(->)` is right-associative:

```
id :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
```

showing that `id`'s type fits the form `a -> b -> c`, where `a` is `b -> c`. In other words, we can reshape `id`'s type to fit the required form simply by specialising the general type it already has.

Another way to understand this is to see that `uncurry ($)` also has the type `(b -> c, b) -> c`. Comparing the definitions of `id` and `($)`:

```
id :: a -> a
id a = a

($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) f x = f x
```

we can make the latter definition more point-free:

```
($) f = f
```

at which point the fact that `($)` is simply a specialisation of `id` to a more specific type becomes clear.

Comment: Thanks! That's starting to make sense! I still find it a bit of a spinout!

Comment: @ssanj: If it's any consolation, writing this as `uncurry id` rather than `uncurry ($)` is evil :)

Comment: And if you want to be particularly evil, you could write `(\`id\` 3)` instead of `($ 3)` or define `id` as `infixr 0 \`id\`` and use it instead of `($)`, such as `(^2) \`id\` 1 + 2 * 3`.

Answer (score 8):

> How can you use id (a -> a) as the first parameter to uncurry, which requires a (a -> b -> c) function?

Actually, `uncurry` requires `(a -> (b -> c))` function. Can you spot the difference? :)

Omitting parentheses is evil (well, sometimes). It makes it impossible for a novice to decipher Haskell. Of course after you've gathered some experience with the language, you feel like you don't need them at all, anymore.

Here, it all becomes clear once we write out all the omitted parentheses back explicitly:

```
uncurry :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> ((a,b) -> c)
id      ::  a ->    a
```

Now, writing `uncurry id` calls for a type unification of `a1 -> a1` with `a2 -> (b -> c)`. This is straightforward, `a1 ~ a2` and `a1 ~ (b -> c)`. Just mechanical stuff, **no creative thinking involved** here. So `id` in question actually has type `a -> a where a ~ (b -> c)`, and so `uncurry id` has type `(b -> c,b) -> c`, by simple substitution of `a ~ (b -> c)` into `(a,b) -> c`. That is, it expects a pair of a `b -> c` function and a `b` value, and must produce a `c` value.

Since the types are most general (i.e. nothing is known about them, and so there's no specific functions to call that might do the trick in some special way), the *only way* to produce a `c` value here is to *call* the `b -> c` function with the `b` value as an argument. Naturally, that's what `($)` does. So `uncurry id == uncurry ($)`, although `id` is most certainly *not* `($)`.

Comment: `uncurry f (x,y) = f x y ; id z = z ; uncurry id (x,y) = id x y = x y ; uncurry id = \(x,y) -> x y ; uncurry id :: (a -> b, a) -> b`.